# iOS App PayPal payments between users

Tags: ios, paypal

I would like to create an app similar to eBay. My question is can I allow my users to directly pay to each other using PayPal or Stripe SDKs for iOS ? Example I am the owner of the app and distribute the app on App Store. Users are creating accounts and start selling stuffs. Can 1 user purchase something from another using PayPal or Stripe without involving me ?

Comment: I also want to make payments in real world with PayPal in iOS. But my app is rejected. Looking for solution too.